# Как оформить post запрос axios во vuex?

Tags: vue.js

маюсь очень долго.

есть fake api.
http://localhost:3000/items - тут вручную были добавлены определенные товары

добавление товара работает на клиенте. но при обновлении данные не сохраняются. могу ли я как-нибудь "зафиксировать" добавленные данные?

есть кнопка "Добавить товар"

```
    <button class="add_btn" @click="ADD_TO_PRODUCTS(item)">Добавить товар</button>
```

store.js:

```
    actions:
        async ADD_TO_PRODUCTS({commit}, item){
            const response = await axios.post(' http://localhost:3000/items', item);
            commit ('SET_PRODUCT_TO_STATE', response.data)
}
...
mutations:
        SET_PRODUCT_TO_STATE: (state, item) =>{
            let cloneItem = {...item}
            state.items.push(cloneItem);
        },
```

Выдает ошибку, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

вы можете зафиксировать список добавивь к нему новое значение и vue за вас отобразить автоматически изменение в списке или обновить страницу если в backend данные сохраняются